# How do i use assert_select to check for the absence of certain content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assert, functional-testing, assertions

An example use case is making sure that the response HTML does not have escaped HTML characters which could imply that html_safe was not used where needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper method you could add to the ActionController::TestCase class in test_helper.rb

```
def assert_no_escaped_html
  assert_select "body", { :text => /&lt;.*&gt;/, :count => 0 }, "This page must contain no HTML escaped '<', '>' characters\nContent - #{@response.body}"
end
```

Call this assertion in your functional tests